# Error at pushbroker.StopAllServices (PushSharp)

Tags: push-notification, pushsharp

I am encountering an exception (not always but frequently) in my push service when pushing to Windows Phone.  Exception is showing "one or more errors occurred" at the point where StopAllServices is called.  The push service reports these errors only when pushing to windows phone, so I am at this point thinking I am doing something wrong with the Windows code.  Could a pushsharp guru please have a look at the code and advise?  (i.e. Redth - Im pretty new to asking questions here, can we tag people to get their attention?)  The ambiguous error is returned in the catch of the StopAllBrokers() method

```
protected override void OnTimer(ElapsedEventArgs e, ref bool StopService)
    {

        try
        {
            if (!ServiceState.Instance.RequestLock())
            {
                WriteLogEntry("Skipping MobileEx.Push.Service[" + Lib.AppPath + "]. In use", LogBase.EEventType.Warning);

                return;
            }

            int LoopCount = 0;

            while (LoopCount < Panztel.Shared.General.Settings.AppSettings.GetSettingValue("ProcessLimit", "100"))
            {
                LoopCount += 1;

                if (StopRequested)
                    break;

                using (var MyScope = new TransactionScope())
                {
                    var MyContext = DataContextHelper.NewContext;

                    var MyId = Guid.NewGuid();
                    Mobile.API.BusinessLogic.Data.Push MyItem = null;

                    try
                    {
                        MyItem = PushLogic.GrabItemToProcess(MyId, ref MyContext);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        WriteLogEntry("Unable to get push item to process. " + ex.Message, LogBase.EEventType.Error);
                    }

                    if (MyItem == null)
                        break; // Drop out as nothing to process.

                    MyItem.ProcessId = MyId;

                    var MyApplications = PushLogic.GetPushApplicationListByPushId(MyItem.PushId, MyItem.CompanyLinkId, ref MyContext);

                    foreach (var MyPushApp in MyApplications)
                    {
                        var MyPhoneApp = PhoneLogic.GetPhoneApplicationItem(MyPushApp.PhoneId, MyPushApp.ApplicationId);

                        if (MyPhoneApp == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(MyPhoneApp.PushChannelUri))
                        {
                            // Mark as failed and continue
                            MyPushApp.ProcessState = 15;
                            continue;
                        }

                        var MyQueue = GetPushBroker(MyItem.Phone.OsType, MyPhoneApp);

                        if (MyQueue == null)
                        {
                            MyPushApp.ProcessState = 16;
                            continue;
                        }

                        switch (MyItem.Phone.OsType)
                        {
                            case 1: // Android
                                var MyMsgHelper = new PushMessageHelper();

                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(MyItem.Message))
                                    MyMsgHelper.AddItem("alert", MyItem.Message);

                                MyMsgHelper.AddItem("badge", "1");
                                MyMsgHelper.AddItem("pushtypeid", MyItem.PushTypeId.ToString());
                                MyMsgHelper.AddItem("notify", MyItem.IsNotificationRequired ? "1" : "0");

                                if (MyItem.LastrvNo.HasValue)
                                    MyMsgHelper.AddItem("lastrvno", MyItem.LastrvNo.Value.ToString());

                                var MessageInJson = MyMsgHelper.GetJsonMessage();

                                var MyNotification = new GcmNotification()
                                    .ForDeviceRegistrationId(MyPhoneApp.PushChannelUri)
                                    .WithCollapseKey("key_" + MyItem.PushId)
                                    .WithJson(MessageInJson)
                                    .WithTag(MyId.ToString());

                                MyQueue.QueueNotification(MyNotification);
                                break;

                            case 2: // Windows
                                //******************    RAW     *********************************//
                                var ThisMsgHelper = new PushMessageHelper();

                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(MyItem.Message))
                                {
                                    ThisMsgHelper.AddItem("alert", MyItem.Message);
                                }

                                ThisMsgHelper.AddItem("badge", "1");
                                ThisMsgHelper.AddItem("pushtypeid", MyItem.PushTypeId.ToString());
                                ThisMsgHelper.AddItem("notify", MyItem.IsNotificationRequired ? "1" : "0");

                                if (MyItem.LastrvNo.HasValue)
                                    ThisMsgHelper.AddItem("lastrvno", MyItem.LastrvNo.Value.ToString());

                                var MessageInXml = ThisMsgHelper.GetWp8PushMessage();
                                var MyWindowsNotification = new WindowsPhoneRawNotification();
                                MyWindowsNotification.ForEndpointUri(new Uri(MyPhoneApp.PushChannelUri));
                                MyWindowsNotification.ForOSVersion(WindowsPhoneDeviceOSVersion.Eight);
                                MyWindowsNotification.WithBatchingInterval(BatchingInterval.Immediate);
                                MyWindowsNotification.WithRaw(MessageInXml);
                                MyWindowsNotification.Tag = MyId.ToString();

                                MyQueue.QueueNotification(MyWindowsNotification);

                                break;

                            case 3: // iPhone
                                var MyAppleNotification = new AppleNotification()
                                    .ForDeviceToken(MyPhoneApp.PushChannelUri)
                                    .WithTag(MyId.ToString())
                                    .WithCustomItem("pushtypeid", MyItem.PushTypeId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

                                var MyMsg = MyItem.Message;
                                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(MyMsg))
                                {
                                    if (MyItem.IsNotificationRequired)
                                    {
                                        switch (MyItem.PushTypeId)
                                        {
                                            case 3:
                                                MyMsg = "New schedule(s) received";
                                                break;

                                            case 4:
                                                MyMsg = "New message(s) received";
                                                break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                // if request location, add in the bit to do a background notification
                                // http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/part_3_ios_backgrounding_techniques/updating_an_application_in_the_background/

                                if (MyItem.PushTypeId == 5)
                                    MyAppleNotification = MyAppleNotification.WithContentAvailable(1);

                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(MyMsg))
                                    MyAppleNotification = MyAppleNotification.WithAlert(MyMsg).WithBadge(1);

                                if (MyItem.IsNotificationRequired)
                                    MyAppleNotification = MyAppleNotification.WithSound("beep.aiff").WithBadge(1);

                                if (MyItem.LastrvNo.HasValue)
                                    MyAppleNotification = MyAppleNotification.WithCustomItem("lastrvno", MyItem.LastrvNo.Value.ToString());

                                MyQueue.QueueNotification(MyAppleNotification);
                                break;

                        }

                        MyPushApp.ProcessState = 5;
                    }

                    MyItem.ProcessState = 5;
                    PushLogic.UpdateItem(ref MyContext, MyItem);

                    MyScope.Complete();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteLogEntry("Error in MobileEx.Push.Service.PushWorker.OnTimer - " + ex.Message, LogBase.EEventType.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                StopAllBrokers();
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                WriteLogEntry("Error in MobileEx.Push.Service.PushWorker.OnTimer.StopAllBrokers - " + Ex.Message, LogBase.EEventType.Error);
            }

        }
        ServiceState.Instance.ReleaseLock();

    }

    private PushBroker GetPushBroker(short OsType, PhoneApplication MyPhoneApp)
    {
        PushBroker MyBroker;
        string Key = OsType + "." + MyPhoneApp.Application.PackageName.ToLower();

        if (_PushList == null)
            _PushList = new Dictionary<string, PushBroker>();

        if (_PushList.ContainsKey(Key))
        {
            MyBroker = _PushList[Key];
        }
        else
        {
            MyBroker = new PushBroker();
            MyBroker.OnNotificationFailed += Push_OnNotificationFailed;
            MyBroker.OnDeviceSubscriptionExpired += Push_OnDeviceSubscriptionExpired;
            MyBroker.OnNotificationSent += Push_OnNotificationSent;
            MyBroker.OnChannelException += MyBroker_OnChannelException;
            MyBroker.OnServiceException += MyBroker_OnServiceException;

            switch (OsType)
            {
                case 1: // Android
                    var SenderId = MyPhoneApp.Application.ProductGroup.SenderId;
                    var SenderAuth = MyPhoneApp.Application.ProductGroup.SenderAuth;
                    var PackageName = MyPhoneApp.Application.PackageName;

                    var MyGoogleChannelSettings = new GcmPushChannelSettings(SenderId, SenderAuth, PackageName);
                    MyBroker.RegisterGcmService(MyGoogleChannelSettings);

                    break;

                case 2: // Windows
                    MyBroker.RegisterWindowsPhoneService();
                    break;

                case 3: // iPhone
                    var CertificateFile = Panztel.Shared.General.Settings.AppSettings.GetSetting("ApplePushCertificate", "");
                    var CertificatePassword = Panztel.Shared.General.Settings.AppSettings.GetSetting("ApplePushCertificatePassword", "");
                    var IsProduction = Panztel.Shared.General.Settings.AppSettings.GetSettingValue("ApplePushProduction", "0") == 1;

                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(CertificateFile) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(CertificatePassword))
                        throw new Exception("Apple Push Certificate settings not configured");

                    if (!File.Exists(CertificateFile))
                        throw new Exception("Apple Push Certificate [" + CertificateFile + "] not found");

                    var CertificateData = File.ReadAllBytes(CertificateFile);
                    var MyAppleChannelSettings = new ApplePushChannelSettings(IsProduction, CertificateData, CertificatePassword);

                    // need to limit the number of channels we have for Apple otherwise they can return 
                    // "The maximum number of Send attempts to send the notification was reached!"

                    var MyServiceSettings = new PushServiceSettings();
                    MyServiceSettings.MaxAutoScaleChannels = 5;
                    MyServiceSettings.AutoScaleChannels = true;

                    MyBroker.RegisterAppleService(MyAppleChannelSettings, MyServiceSettings);                        
                    break;
            }

            _PushList.Add(Key, MyBroker);
        }

        return MyBroker;
    }

    private void StopAllBrokers()
    {
        if (_PushList == null)
            return;

        foreach (var MyItem in _PushList)
        {
            try
            {
                MyItem.Value.StopAllServices();
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                WriteLogEntry("Error in MobileEx.Push.Service.PushWorker.OnTimer.StopAllBrokers.StopAllServices - " + Ex.Message, LogBase.EEventType.Error);
            }

        }

        _PushList = null;
    }
```

`

Comment: I'm no expert, but if you provide a test app of around 20 lines of essential code, it would be a lot easier to help you.